# How to create audio stream pre buffer like sveriges radio iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, stream, buffer

I've download this app and i search since long time how to create the pre buffer.

For example:
I click on play 
My app load the stream in the buffer
After 10 seconds (my buffer get 10 seconds in advance)
I start the stream for the first 10 secs (i've got 10 secs if my reachability failed or something else)
When my phone is unreachable (my stream continue for 10 sec and the buffer is empty) if the reachability is back (rebuffed & play)

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sveriges-radio-play/id300548244?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

This is a really broad question. You're going to have to play with NSURLRequest to get your raw data of X seconds into a local byte buffer. The 10 seconds you will have to calculate based on the type of data coming in (i.e. mp3 @ 8Khz etc). Once you do that, you can start throwing your data into an AudioQueue (which has its own buffers).

Comment: I'll try with NSURLRequest thanks for your answer. So i can download 30 seconds of stream during 10sec if i say i want to download 3x128kbps (my stream is actualy in 128kbps) I can download 3 times faster? I try using buffer with audiostream class without success...

Comment: The first time you try to get your audio playing, it will be tricky. However, make sure you read the Audio Queue services programming guide and follow the examples. It's a bit of a pain at first, but once you get it working, it will make sense.

Comment: First time i want to download the burst and after playing the stream.

If my stream cut, i download the burst again...

Is there an example in Objective-C for that ? 
I think RadioKit can make it : http://stormyprods.com/products/radiokit.php But it's too expensive and if we can buy it we can't see how it's works :/